# How to fix 'route.search' error in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've started a simple app with Express (and Node) and I am barely setting it up but I've already come across an error I can't seem to find a solution to.

I've tried googling the problem and I've gone through a couple somewhat similar Stack Overflow posts but I cannot solve it and it's driving me a little insane.

Here is my starter code (saved on a file named app.js not index.js)

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blog_app", {useNewUrlParser: true});
app.search("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
// title
// image 
// body
// created


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Server is running!");
});
```

And when I run 'node app.js' on my terminal to see if my server is running, I get this error:
[image: node error]

Instead of getting the message "Server is running!"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: use app.set() for setting view engine not app.search()

Comment: See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use app.set instead of app.search to set the view engine

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```